# How to get input of arguments from the terminal along with the filename in python?

Tags: python, input, command, sys

For example if I want to compare two numbers(compare which is greater, for example) and get this input from the terminal in linux along with the filename.

Like:

```
python myfilename.py 2 3
```

This program should output 3.
I think that this can be done with the help of sys module.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/stdlib.html#command-line-arguments or for a more powerful module, http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

Comment: `python myfilename.py 2 3 & echo 3` should output 3

Comment: I recommend [argparse](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html).

Comment: I think argparse is an overkill for such a simple use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sys.argv` like in:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```